# store dynamic JPA Queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In a webproject i have a complex form to build a dynamic query. When i wrote this code I only had JPA 1, (no Criteria API) so i build the query String dynamicly (but still use bind parameters). This works fine so far. Now i want to save the Query (not the result) so the user can re-run the same query later.

Idealisticaly, i would just store the query string in the db. While constructing the query, i could make sure only using the IDs (not "where user = :user" but "where user.id = :userid").

As the input to the parameters comes from the user, i like to use query parameters, to avoid ['little bobby tables'](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is a problem because I see no reason for you to just make a table to store the queries in.
The tricky part must be in 
1) Getting the available parameters from somewhere. Maybe you can store that in a parameters table if needed.
2) Deciding which parameters to set. Just find all :parameters in the query query, see if you got that parameter available and set it on the query.

What am I missing?

Comment: You not missing something. I was just hoping that I do not need to implement that on my own. Its not rocket sience, but one would need to store the parameters and there positions. Type would be always String.

Comment: You do not need to store the position, just the name of the parameter.